# Does AVCaptureSession change a Capture Devices dimensions?

Tags: macos, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I have a AVCaptureSession with a single Video AVCaptureDevice connected.
I would like to use the following session presets:

- AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
- AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium
- AVCaptureSessionPresetLow

I thought that these would set the dimensions of an AVCaptureDevices dimensions to the following respectively:

- 1280 x 720
- 640 x 480
- 320 x 240

Or at least there abouts, giving 3 distinct resolutions and settings.

My default Capture Device (Facetime Camera) does indeed have these dimensions, and I'm able to change them directly on the Capture Devices, but when setting the session preset like so:

> if session.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium) {
>       session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium }

All presets take the Capture Devices format to the highest dimensions; 1280 x 720, Pixel Format; 420v and Frame Rate Ranges; 1-30.

Looking at the AVRecorder Demo the Preset setting acts differently and changes the dimensions... Any ideas?

Comment: guess it is using default value of sessionPreset that is `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`. Are you sure? setting session preset actually works by checking with breakpoints?

Comment: AVCaptureSessionPreset is definitely getting set on the Session, and it changes aspects of the AVCaptureDevice such as the Pixel Format back to 420v. It's just not touching the dimensions... I'm not not locking for configuration but wonder if a capture device gets locked if a specific format attribute is changed directly?

Comment: Got the same problem, setSessionPreset does nothing (always 1280x720), on a MacBook.